# Get if there's been a record in the last week

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to calculate if a customer is recurrent or not. Recurrent clients are defined if it has an activity in the past week.

I have a table like this:

```
DATE       | Document | CUSTOMER
2018-08-14 | 12038120 | A
```

So far I am able to only get a count of activities per customer per date. But I'm kinda lost on how to count from today to the past 7 days.

So far I have this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

df= df.set_index('Date')
df= df.sort_index()

df= df.groupby(['Customer', 'Date'])['Document'].count()
```

Thanks

Comment: What format is this table in? Is it already parsed into a Python structure? Do you have any code examples of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Have you made any start on this at all, like converting to a datetime?

Answer (score 1):

Use the datetime module.

```
#convert string to datetime object
datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-08-14", '%Y-%m-%d')

# check if now is within 7 days of the above string
if datetime.datetime.now()-datetime_object<datetime.timedelta(days=7):
    print True
```